# What could be wrong with this syntax pharos?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, pharo-5

I am trying to create a method that logs to a server, grabs the json file it found, then selects 4 of each element and sends it to an address. My code below seems to work when I give it only a single data known for each format in the send link rather than a loop that should select each at a time. The error I'm getting is: `instance of smallInteger did not understand #readStream`. What is causing this error? How else can I automate these requests?

```html
1 to: 4 do: [ :each |
   each.
   a := ZnClient new.
   a get: 'https://MyServer/'.
   a headerAt: 'referer' put: 'https://MyServer' ;
     formAt: 'email' add: 'myEmail' ;
     formAt: 'password' add: 'MyPass'.
   a post.
   a get: 'https://MyServer/json'.

   data := NeoJSONReader fromString: a contents.
   list := data at: each.
   foo := list at: 'num'.
   poo := list at: 'name'.
    
   a get: 'https://MyServer/copy/', poo.
   a url: 'https://MyServer/send/'.
   a formAt: 'add' add: 'given address' ;
     formAt: 'nb_pic' add: foo ;
     formAt: 'identf' add: poo.

   a post.
   a get: 'https://MyServer/json' ]
```

Comment: Doesn't the Pharo environment tell you what line is the culprit? Did you examine the debug windows that pop up? Or are you using GNU Smalltalk? It's not clear since you've tagged both.

Comment: What debugging steps have you performed to narrow this down?

Comment: I would assume that ``formAt: 'nb_pic' add: foo ;`` is the culprit line as foo is probably an integer. 
You could step through the code or use debugger to pinpoint the issue...

Comment: @Carlo , foo is actually an integer which denote the value of the formAt: 'nb_pic'. In the form action it expects a number. when I give each formAt a known value without using the loop and data, it works but when I include the part with data to poo it sends the error.

Comment: Pharo gives you a fairly detailed trace of each message being sent and all of the arguments and variables within that method call in the error window as you click on each item in that window. You should be able to get a lot more detail than just "when I include the part with data to poo it sends the error" which should help you.

Comment: Thanks @lurker. I am new to Pharo and I hardly understand its debug. While I was using it to find the bug it was just sending me error at the last post. I realized what was wrong. Thanks

Comment: The debug window in Pharo is very thorough and helpful. If you explore it, you'll find lots of details that will help you figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, there is nothing wrong with the syntax.
But looks like you didn't get the API of the framework you are using: you send `get` and `post` messages without understand that they will actually execute a "http get" and "http post" each time you send them.

So, while the "syntax" it self is ok, what is very incorrect is what you are doing (Which I do not understand what is). Look, this is how your program can be understood:

```
4 timesRepeat: [
    "this will do a post" 
    ZnClient new
        url: 'https://MyServer/';
        headerAt: 'referer' put: 'https://MyServer';
        formAt: 'email' add: 'myEmail';
        formAt: 'password' add: 'MyPass';
        post.

    "this is a simple get"
    a := ZnClient get: 'https://MyServer/json'.
    data := NeoJSONReader fromString: a contents.
    list := data at:each.
    foo := list at:'num'.
    poo := list at:'name'.

    "this is another get that I don't know what's doing here"
    a := ZnClient get: 'https://MyServer/copy/', poo.

    "this is another post"
    a := ZnClient 
        url: 'https://MyServer/send/';
        formAt: 'add' add: 'given address';
        formAt: 'nb_pic' add:foo;
        formAt: 'identf' add: poo;
        post.

    "and finally, this is another get"
    ZnClient get: 'https://MyServer/json' ]
```

clearly, that code is not doing what you want it to do :)

Comment: Dear @EstebanLM the last get is the form action <form action="/copy/" method="post"> at which the file has to be send. Basically you collect the file then append it to the action form with a method post for send. Like mentioned before when I introduce the loop for selecting each file, get the value foo and poo for the last post it gives error while which work fine when giving value directly for the post form.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out thanks to @Carlo hint that the error message: instance of smallInteger did not understand #readStream was due to the values collected from poo and foo.

```html
    list := data at:each.
    foo := list at:'num'. "Here and integer"
    poo := list at:'name'."Here a byteString"
```

In fact the form action expects a key and value like shown, however the value has to be a string which I was not doing right by just substituting poo and foo to add:

```
    formAt: 'nb_pic' add:foo;
    formAt: 'identf' add: poo;
```

Therefore I needed to convert foo and poo asString and Now it works fine. Thanks